# SWT: draw "icons" in table or tree cells

Tags: java, icons, swt, jface

We are having a Swing application which we plan to port to SWT/JFace. The Swing application draws a lot of icons (`javax.swing.Icon` implementations) in trees and tables (icon left to the text). If I understood it correctly, SWT only can draw *images* (aka graphic files). What would be the simplest solution to paint the icon or entire table/tree cell? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Images can be loaded from graphic files, or they can be drawn in-memory.

```
Image image = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), width, height);
GC gc = new GC(image);

// draw icon using GC

gc.dispose();
```

As far as displaying them in tables/trees, the most direct approach is to set the image on the table/tree item:

```
TableItem item = ...
item.setImage(theImage);
```

There is one significant drawback to this approach however: on Windows, the first time you set an image on a table item, that image's height becomes the standard height for all items in the table.  So if you set a larger image, it will be scaled down to the first image's size.  If you set a smaller image, it will be scaled up.

If all your images are the same size, this will not be a problem.

However if you can not predict the size of the images in advance, I recommend using the [custom draw API](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html) to render your table/tree items.  This approach is definitely more intensive but gives you fine-grained control over the result.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a place where the Image can be set on demand immediately before drawing the node?

Comment: You can use a SWT.VIRTUAL table and use a SWT.SetData listener to set the image and text as needed.